# QMake relinks targets when it is unnesessary

Tags: c++, qt, build, target, qmake

Is it normal that QMake relinks targets in the following case:

```
qmake
make <- build = compile + link
make <- relink
make <- relink
...
make <- relink
```

**NOTE:** I do not change the source code between these consecutive `make` invocations.

**NOTE:** It does not rebuild them from scratch, but rather relinks.

How come then that it relinks executables, shared libraries, and static libraries? It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: As a possibility, it can be that some of the dates/times are off - like manifest/some other link related file is from the future, so it relinks it?

Comment: Of course, hypothetically this can be the case, but I can't see any reason for it to happen on my machine. In particular, other build systems are doing well.

Comment: Can you supply more info, like your OS, tool versions, Qt version and type (e.g. Commercial) - and your .pro file

Comment: You could check if there is actually a bad file date somewhere with a command like `make -d | grep "is newer\\|Must remake"`.